# Can't compile qt project with static lib curl

Tags: c++, qt, curl, static-libraries

I am trying to compile a qt project with qtcurl using a statically built curl.

I am using the following to build a minimalist curl static library:

```
./configure --disable-shared --enable-static --prefix=/tmp/curl --disable-ldap --disable-sspi --without-librtmp --disable-ftp --disable-file --disable-dict --disable-telnet --disable-tftp --disable-rtsp --disable-pop3 --disable-imap --disable-smtp --disable-gopher --disable-smb --without-libidn --enable-ares
```

I am including
`-L/tmp/curl/lib/libcurl.a`
in the LIBS of the project, and 
`/tmp/curl/include`
in the INCLUDEPATH

This is the output that I am getting:

```
QtCUrl.o: In function `QtCUrl::QtCUrl()':
QtCUrl.cpp:(.text+0x10d): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
QtCUrl.o: In function `QtCUrl::~QtCUrl()':
QtCUrl.cpp:(.text+0x32e): undefined reference to `curl_slist_free_all'
QtCUrl.cpp:(.text+0x355): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
QtCUrl.o: In function `QtCUrl::setOptions(QHash<CURLoption, QVariant>&)':
QtCUrl.cpp:(.text+0xcee): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
QtCUrl.cpp:(.text+0xdac): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
QtCUrl.cpp:(.text+0xee9): undefined reference to `curl_slist_append'
QtCUrl.cpp:(.text+0xfe5): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
QtCUrl.cpp:(.text+0x1078): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
QtCUrl.cpp:(.text+0x109f): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
QtCUrl.cpp:(.text+0x1155): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
QtCUrl.cpp:(.text+0x1290): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
QtCUrl.o: In function `QtCUrl::exec(QHash<CURLoption, QVariant>&)':
QtCUrl.cpp:(.text+0x1f27): undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
QtCUrl.o: In function `curlGlobalInit()':
QtCUrl.cpp:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `curl_global_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Shouldn't the `LIBS` part be `LIBS += -L/tmp/curl/lib -lcurl`?

Comment: `-L` specifies a *directory* to look for libraries in. If you want to link statically, just add the path to the library to the LIBS.